# How to load large json model into three.js project

Tags: node.js, json, graphics, three.js

I am trying to load building models into three.js. The format of models is JSON file generated by [RvtVa3c](https://github.com/va3c/RvtVa3c), which is an add-in for Revit to generating JSON output. Then I used `THREE.ObjectLoader()`  to load the model into three.js just like this example [json loader three.js](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_json_claraio).

Everything is fine with a model with a size below 100MB. As I tried to load a 200MB model, Chrome throws "Aw, snap" error page. And Firefox throws allocation size overflow. Because the `THREE.ObjectLoader()`  uses XHR to read the json file into String in one time and I guess the size of String is to large for java-script. The length of String is over 200,000,000 with 100MB JSON.

So I am seeking a way of loading the JSON file by stream. `JSONStream` in Node.js can handle 200MB JSON. Code example is displayed below.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
JSONStream = require('JSONStream'),
es = require('event-stream');

var getStream = function () {
    var jsonData = 'buildingModel.js',
        stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, {encoding: 'utf8'}),
        parser = JSONStream.parse('*');
        return stream.pipe(parser);
};

getStream()
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }));
```

As browser can not used `require(/module/)` . I tried used `browserify` to bundle `JSONStream` into my codes. However, `fs` can not be browserify.

Here is my questions:

1. Is using stream the best way to load extreme large JSON model in three.js? If not, what is the better solution?
2. Is `fs` can be browserify. Or I can create readable stream in browser with other ways?

Thank you for answering my quesitons.

Comment: Updates : I am trying use regular expression to split the Json file into readable size. And read them then merge into one object. At last used `ObjectLoader()` to load the object

Comment: How did you split it into readable size?

Comment: @user2118784 I read each lines and store the lines into one string var, using regex to remember the data levels and brackets, e.g. by counting the whether `[` matches `]`. If the string size is larger than the upper bound, then make sure the stored data is integrated and was matched with correct brackets. Continue read rest of lines and store into a new String var.

Comment: Is there any people can answer my question?